# UK Visitor visa: Applications in same envelope?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, vfs-global

I am applying for UK visitor visa from Portland USA. I have just finished my and my family's biometrics for UK visitor visa . I wanted to know if we can send 4 applications in one envelope or we have to send it in 4 different envelopes with 4 different shipping labels. Please help me understand as it is very confusing. I was checking VFS global for shipping labels and they also have options for family/ group application label options but there are some issues generating from their website. Please help me if anybody has done it in the past. 
Thank you for ur response in advance.